# Flutter showModalBottomSheet with bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm using bloc in my app, in my showModalBottomSheet there are filters that should apply when the button is clicked, but when the button is clicked I get.
I'm using bloc in my app, in my showModalBottomSheet there are filters that should apply when the button is clicked, but when the button is clicked I get.

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ProductsBloc> above this BottomSheet Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
```

I wrapped my widget in BlocProvider and tried to wrap in BlocProvider.value but it doesn't work.

```
// where it is called from
 appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showFilter(context);
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt),
          ),
        ],

// my modal bottom sheet 
showFilter(context) => showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (context) {
      return BlocProvider<ProductsBloc>(
        create: (context) => ProductsBloc(),
        child: Container(
          padding: REdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 12),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Фильтр',
                    style: TextStyles.bodyStyle,
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.close)),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.h),
              Text(
                'цена'.toUpperCase(),
                style: TextStyles.editStyle,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.h),
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                value: 'price_asc',
                items: const [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: 'price_asc',
                    child: Text('По возрастанию'),
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: 'price_desc',
                    child: Text('По убыванию'),
                  ),
                ],
                menuMaxHeight: 200,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                onChanged: (value) {},
                decoration: Decorations.dropdownDecoration,
                elevation: 1,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.h),
              Text(
                'медиа'.toUpperCase(),
                style: TextStyles.editStyle,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.h),
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                value: '',
                items: const [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: '',
                    child: Text('Все'),
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: 'with_photo',
                    child: Text('C фото'),
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: 'without_photo',
                    child: Text('Без фото'),
                  ),
                ],
                menuMaxHeight: 200,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                onChanged: (value) {},
                decoration: Decorations.dropdownDecoration,
                elevation: 1,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.h),
              Text(
                'наличие'.toUpperCase(),
                style: TextStyles.editStyle,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.h),
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                value: '',
                items: const [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: '',
                    child: Text('Все'),
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: 'in_stock',
                    child: Text('В наличии'),
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: 'out_of_stock',
                    child: Text('Нет в наличии'),
                  ),
                ],
                menuMaxHeight: 200,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                onChanged: (value) {},
                decoration: Decorations.dropdownDecoration,
                elevation: 1,
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<ProductsBloc>().add(LoadProductsWithFilter());
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Применить')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your outer **Container** widget with **Builder** Widget like this

```
child : Builder(
  builder: (context) {
   return // Your Container(...);
},
)
```

And also read about **BuildContext**. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNgwFMm3opE) will help you to understand BuildContext w.r.t BLOC.